# Using CSS variable to store calc() operator

Tags: css, variables

Would there be any complications in using CSS variable instead of standard operator? I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
.element {
    --op: +;
    width: calc(100px var(--op) 10px);
}
```

This way I can change the operator with a class

```
.multiply {
    --op: *;
}
```

I know for a fact that it's working in vanilla CSS (whether intentional or not), however SASS for example is unable to understand what's going on, so I'm confused whether this might be a bad idea that will lead to different problems down the road?

Comment: You're asking for opinions and will get your Q closed, no doubt. I had to try this, didn't know it worked. Now I do, and it works like a charm. However, the SASS struggle alone is reason to not use the trick and it may indeed be an unintentional feature as you suggested. And there's the readability issue: Using *y=mx+b* with `y=0.00625x + 12` will result in something like `html { font-size: calc( var(--m) var(--p1) var(--x) var(--p2) var(--b) ) }` with `p1=*` and `p2=+`. Fun, but no, ...not until there's some *official* W3C document on the subject everyone can read.

Comment: Please provide the SASS File (.scss) that you tried.

Comment: I see how it might seem opinion-based question, yet it really boils down to whether this is something that is officially supported or not. By your comment it appears that it probably isn't. So maybe it's in the "hack" category, which is fine I guess. By the way, I did find a way around SASS by using #{var(--op)} which compiles with no issues.